# Gamma function related?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am just wondering about an integral, which has the form
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2+ax+1)}}$$
which also equivalent to
$$2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+ax^2+1}}$$
do these Integrals have a solution?

I have tried

- completing the square
- trig sub

and failed

Comment: This is a complete elliptic integral: it is directly related to the $\Gamma$ function only for special values of $a$, like $a=1$.

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Done, below. Before I should have said $a=0$, not $a=1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A,B$ have a positive real part,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+A)(x^2+B)}} = \frac{\pi}{2\,\text{AGM}(\sqrt{A},\sqrt{B})}=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{A}}K\left(1-\tfrac{B}{A}\right)=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{B}}K\left(1-\tfrac{A}{B}\right)$$
where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind (denoted according to Mathematica's notation, such that the argument of $K$ is the elliptic modulus) and $\text{AGM}$ is the arithmetic-geometric mean, defined by the common limit of $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}$.

$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ *can* be written in terms of the $\text{AGM}$ (some links on the associated [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function) point back to MSE), hence for particular values of $a$ your integral *is* related to the $\Gamma$ function. It is not in full generality.

Comment: I'm just curious, where can I learn about how did you manage to solve that integral in terms of AGM? Is that related to some higher level mathematics that I never took, like complex analysis, number theory, or whatever? Is it related to distributions? I would like some reference, because I see it as amazing to be able to simply change an integral like this into a discrete function. Thanks, and also +1

Comment: @KKZiomek: I suggest you [*$\pi$ and the $\text{AGM}$*](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/JBCC-Brent.pdf) by Borwein.

Comment: @KKZiomek: You may also have a look at [my posts](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/08/arithmetic-geometric-mean-of-gauss.html?m=0) on this topic (these are based on Borwein's book and may be of help if you don't have access to the book).